# Best way to sync contact information to iOS App

Tags: ios, core-data

In my iPhone app, I want user to

1. Select a contact from addressBook
2. Display it in a **UITableView**
3. Automatically sync between addressBook and my App

I have done point 1 and 2 using **CNContactViewController** and **ContactsUI**.

I am able to update changes to addressBook from my App.

However when I close my App, all selections are lost (no  **persistence**).

I am thinking of storing a contact ID in a local filesystem or **CoreData**. Is this a good way or is there any better way. Is there a functionality to get contact ID - when selecting contacts **AND** also when creating new contacts from my App.

I am **not asking for code**, just a nudge in the correct direction

iOS 9 / Xcode 7

Comment: I am also aware of **CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification** but looking to store contact-ID (objectID or identifier or key) to a local file system / core Data.